# TextBox in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can some one help me out to design below textbox using Bootstrap 5 or only with plane css class textbox
TextBox should be responsive

OnPage load textbox should be with placeholder

```
<div class="form-outline">
 <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control" />
 <label class="form-label" for="form1">Example label</label>
 </div>
```

[image: Onload]

onclick on textbox it label should get upside

[image: OnClick on textbox]

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried

Comment: @Sfili_81 can you please suggest

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this](https://codepen.io/simone/pen/yYjPOK) codepen:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  direction: rtl;
}

fieldset.form-group {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: .6rem;
  left: 1rem;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: text;
}

:focus + label {
  color: #66afe9;
  top: -.9rem;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
 <fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </fieldset>
```